# Mariadb installation on Amazon linux 2

Tags: mariadb-10.4, amazon-linux-2

Can someone provide steps to install mariadb on amazon linux 2?
I am pretty new in linux, so a little detail will be greatly appreciated. I have seen few links to install maria db on centOs but not sure if the same works for Amazon linux 2

Answer (score 9):

Here you go:

1. Install and Start MariaDB

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y mariadb-server
sudo systemctl start mariadb
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```

2. Secure DB server. Select the relevant option's during command run.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

---

But I recommend you to install MariaDB from official repo for latest version by following instructions in [this link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/yum/).

Comment: This link has mentioned as below. It doesn't support Amazon linux 2.

We currently have YUM repositories for the following Linux distributions. 

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6
Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7
CentOS 6
CentOS 7
Fedora 27
Fedora 28
Fedora 29

Comment: Does above commands not working on AL2? (ignore link)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't have access to yum install, rather I have my own code repo which I am trying to install. So i couldn't try. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `sudo yum install mariadb` You'll get MariaDB version 5.5 which is an older version of MariaDB to get the latest version you will need to do the following.

1. `sudo amazon-linux-extras enable lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2=latest`
2. `sudo yum install mariadb mariadb-server`

**Note** This will not work if you have php >= 7.3. If this is the case you must uninstall php before doing the steps above, using `sudo yum erase php-common`

3. `sudo amazon-linux-extras disable lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2=latest`

Now mariadb is installed. I first tried to add centos 7 repo, but wasn't successful in getting it to install correctly.

Comment: I dont have access to amazon linux extras. i tried to use centos 7 repo but failing

Error: MariaDB-compat conflicts with 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.amzn2.x86_64
Error: Package: galera-25.3.29-1.rhel6.el6.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libboost_program_options.so.5()(64bit)

Comment: Looks like you you may have the AL2 MariaDB 5.5 installed try `sudo yum erase mariadb. I believe all amazon linux 2 should have amazon-linux-extras. What AMI are you using?